# Facebook Pull Module with Views

Tags: 7, views, social-network

Does the Facebook Pull Module not work with views? I am trying to use the contextual filter, but I do not see anything for Facebook Pull.

ALL I am trying to do is pull post from my Facebook page to my drupal site. I was trying Facebook Parser, but I can't figure out open graph with the access token. I would rather use Facebook Pull, but I need to use it in views.

Any suggestions

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with views?  Facebook pull already comes with a block that you can use anywhere.

Comment: Trying to MASH Facebook and Tweet Feeds into one block. Easier way for this? Example. Tweet feed>Facebook Feed>Tweet Feed>Facebook feed>

Comment: I did look at the Activity Stream Module that might do the trick seeing I ONLY WANT feeds NOT for users to post from my site. BUT the facebook activity stream module doesn't work for Drupal 7.

Comment: To create a block that alternates between fb and twitter posts you will most certainly need to create a custom module - this is kind of an odd feature and there won't be an existing module to handle it.  facebook pull and twitter pull both come with functions you can use to make your job much easier when building your module. `facebook_pull_render` and `twitter_pull_render`